# Delete file from server: Access to the path is denied

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7.5

I call this function from with my code-behind:
DeleteFile(Server.MapPath("/") + "sitemap_index.xml")

```
Public Shared Function DeleteFile(ByVal filename As String) As Boolean
'deletes file from server
Dim bResult As Boolean = False
Try
    If File.Exists(filename) Then
        'delete file
        File.Delete(filename)
        bResult = True
    Else
        bResult = True
    End If
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
Return bResult
End Function
```

I then get the error: Access to the path 'E:\zz\wwwroot\sitemap_index.xml' is denied.

In other sites of myself this logic works great, however on the current site it doesnt. I checked the security settings on my windows server 2008 R2 Standard.

See here the settings I have on my Windows server on folder wwwroot:

> SYSTEM: Full Control
>   NETWORK SERVICE: Read + Write + Read & Execute + List folder contents
>   IIS_IUSRS: Read + Write

As was suggested by other posts I've been reading I tried adding other user groups, but I have no ASPNET service/group on my server.

When logged in as administrator (Forms authentication) I can click a button to recreate the sitemap_index.xml and sitemaps.xml
Users should be able to delete and add images to the wwwroot\images\uploads folder

Which group should I give what permissions to allow the above to be possible AND secure?

Comment: What user does the application pool run under in IIS?  Make sure that user has access.

Comment: When I go to 'basic settings' and check under 'physical path' I see Connect as 'Administrator'. I also see that usergroup Administrators has Full Control access (grayed out) on folder wwwroot

Comment: Where are you seeing those settings?  That doesn't sound like IIS.

Comment: I goto IIS7.5, click on my website and then on the right I see: 'Basic Settings'. There I see Application Pool is set to 'ASP.NET v4.0', Physical path is 'E:\zz\wwwroot' and Connect as 'Administrator'

Comment: In that Basic Settings dialog, you'll see a field called "Application Pool".  Note what it says in that box.  Then in the tree on the left, click on "Application Pools".  Find the application pool with the name you just wrote down. Right click, Advanced Settings, take note what it says next to "Identity".  That is the user that you should check the access for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the access for the Application Pool user.

Find the application pool that your site is using, right click on it and choose `Advanced Settings...`.  The name of the user that the pool is using is listed next to `Identity`.

Note that if the identity says "ApplicationPoolIdentity", you should check the access for the user `IIS AppPool\<Name of the app pool here>` [Info about ApplicationPoolIdentity](http://blogs.iis.net/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/10/02/tip-98-did-you-know-the-default-application-pool-identity-in-iis-7-5-windows-7-changed-from-networkservice-to-apppoolidentity.aspx)

---

It looks like `Modify` permissions are [required to delete files](http://www.techexams.net/forums/server-70-290/19589-ntfs-permission-modify-delete-subfolders-files.html).  Try granting NetworkService `Modify` permissions.

Comment: Identity property says 'NetworkService'. As you can see I've already provided that user with  Read + Write + Read & Execute + List folder contents permissions...or is there something else I should add?

Comment: @See my edit.  I looks like you need to grant Modify permissions (or full control) to NetworkService.

Comment: that answer is just absolutely precise and helpful and exactly made it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. When I applied the codes in this way, I did not encounter any permission requests.

```
    public void DeleteDirectory(string target_dir)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(target_dir);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(target_dir);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            System.IO.File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
            System.IO.File.Delete(file);
        }

        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            DeleteDirectory(dir);
        }

        Directory.Delete(target_dir, false);
    }
```